# Proving Uniform Continuity using Bolzano Weierstrass

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

I have been working on this question for some times, and can't seem to put together the contradiction needed using Bolzano. any help would be greatly appreciated,[image: Question on Uniform Continuity]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence $(x_n)$ must have a monotone subsequence $(x_{n_k})$. Since $(x_{n_k})$ is bounded and monotone, it converges to a point $z\in [a,b]$. Then show $(c_{n_k})$ also converges to $z$. Use the continuity of $f$ and the fact $|f(x_n)-f(c_n)|\ge \varepsilon$ to derive a contradiction.